# Film or show where a space crew set off for Mars and lose communication with Earth due to a war

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

A space crew take off from Earth on a mission to Mars (I think). As they take off, war breaks out on Earth and they are left with no communication.

English, live action. One guy ejects himself via an airlock - later it shows him surrounded by aliens and he realises he's in a sim.

Comment: Can you give us some more details please. When did you watch it? Was it in English or some other language? Animated or live action? As you are new to the site you might want to look at the guide on how to improve your question... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: English, live action. One guy ejects himself via an airlock - later it shows him surrounded by aliens and he realises hes in a sim

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out this morning. This is the New Twilight Zone episode [*Six Degrees of Freedom*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9199164/) (2019).

> “Six Degrees of Freedom” tells the story of a group of astronauts who have been chosen to lead a mission to Mars. Moments before their launch, though, they receive a radio transmission which suggests that North Korea has just launched nuclear missiles. Now facing the unenviable position of living on a planet devastated by nuclear war, the crew make the difficult decision to head to Mars as planned and deal with whatever may come next.
>
> <sub><sup>[Den of Geek Review](https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/the-twilight-zone-review-six-degrees-of-freedom/)</sup></sub>

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a few links to explain how this episode matches the original description.

Comment: Thank you - much appreciated